# How to download file using headless (gui-less) Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, file, selenium, download, selenium-chromedriver

I need to download files using headless web browser in Java. I checked HtmlUnit where I was able to download file in some simple cases but I was not able to download when Ajax initialized downloading (actually it is more complicated as there are two requests, the first one download the URL where the second request actually download file from the given URL). I have replaced HtmlUnit with Selenium. I already checked two WebDrivers, HtmlUnitDriver and ChromeDriver.

- HtmlUnitDriver - similar behaviour like HtmlUnit
- ChromeDriver - I am able to download files in visible mode but when I turned on headless mode, files are no longer downloaded

  ```
  ChromeOptions lChromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  HashMap<String, Object> lChromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  lChromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
  lChromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", _PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD_DIR);
  lChromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", lChromePrefs);
  lChromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

  return new ChromeDriver(lChromeOptions);
  ```

I know that downloading files in headless mode is turned off because of security reasons but there must be some workaround

---

I used 2.28 httpunit before, few minutes ago I started to work with 2.29 but still it seems that Ajax function stops somewhere. This is the way I retrieve data after click and expect a file data: _link.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream()

Does WebConnectionWrapper shows all the requests/responses that are made on the website? Do You know how can I debug this to have better insight? I see that the first part of the Ajax function after link is clicked is being properly called (there are 2 http requests in this function). I even tried to create my custom http request to retrive data/file after first response is fetched inside `WebConnectionWrapper -> getResponse` but it returns 404 error which indicates that this second request had been somehow done but I dont see any log/debug information neither in `_link.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream()` nor `WebConnectionWrapper -> getResponse()`

Comment: HtmlUnit works fine here for all the ajax magic done by PrimeFaces. If you like we can try to help you with this. But you have to share more details and maybe the HtmlUnit user list is the place to discuss issues like this.

Comment: Actually I cant provide here the link to the website I work with but when working with HtmlUnit I used: WebConnectionWrapper and debug every request/response. The Ajax function stopped in the middle (after first HTTP request was done, the second HTTP request to download the needed data/file didnt appear). The ajax functions are obfuscated so it would be useless to put them here

Comment: If you use some kind of library maybe there is a chance to find a public demo. Without having a chance to debug this it is tricky to guess what is going wrong. Have you used the latest version? The version 2.28 had some great improvements regarding promises. Maybe it it worth to try the latest one (2.29 from yesterday ;-)

Comment: I checked 2.29v and added to the topic additional information

Answer (score 0):

Regarding HtmlUnit you can try this:

Calling click() on a dom element is a sync call. This means, this returns after the response of this call is retrieved and processed. Usually all the JS libs out there doing some async magic (like starting some processing with setTimeout(,10) for various (good) reasons. Your code will be aware of this.

A better approach is to do something like this

```
Page page = _link.click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
```

Sometimes the Ajax requests are doing an redirect to the new content. We have to address this new stuff by checking the current window content

```
page = page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();
```

Or maybe better
In case of downloads the (binary) response might be opened in a new window

```
WebWindow tmpWebWindow = webClient.getCurrentWindow();
tmpWebWindow = tmpWebWindow.getTopWindow();
page = tmpWebWindow.getEnclosedPage();
```

This might be the response you are looking for.

```
page.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
```

Its a bit tricky to guess what is going on with your web application. If you like you can reach me via private mail or discuss this in the HtmlUnit user mailing list.

Comment: Ok so I have checked all those options and there is always some html code, not the actual response from internal AJAX request which should return CSV-formatted text. I have no idea how to debug this using HtmlUnit. Im not sure about HtmlUnit hierarchy but I would expect to have this response in currentWindow if Ajax function really does not stop in the middle :/

Comment: Regarding the currentWindow - HtmlUnit always needs a window for content. Usually your browser opens the file dialog to give you the option to save the downloaded file to your disk - in this case opens HtmlUnti a new window containing your file as content.

Comment: As starting point i suggest to use a web proxy like Charles or Fiddler. Enable the proxy for your real browser and capture the traffic for your case. Than run the same case with HtmlUnit over the proxy and capture the traffic also. Than compare.... As starting point figure out if the csv data are send over the wire or if HtmlUnit does not ask for the data at all. If you like you can send me a private mail with your code and i will have a look.